# Accordion slider, not displaying content properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this multi-tiered accordion slider for listing schedules. The problem I am having is once you navigate to the third tier, the entire list disappears and has some weird space at the top. If you follow this link -- [Pool League Demo](http://barret.co/resources/GPL/index.html)

You can see what I mean once you navigate to the schedules tab. Once there, if you click monday 9 ball > Week 1 , you will see exactly what I mean. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Also, on a side note, I am using scrollIt.js and for some reason am having problems with the active class. When applied, it doesn't do what it is supposed to, and this happens multiple times throughout the page, even in the schedules section which doesn't use scrollit.js. If anyone knows how to get the active class to work, I would really appreciate the help on that as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For your first problem just need to clear the floats on the `li` elements

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

For your second answer, please try adding the `activeClass: 'active'` parameter to the  `$.scrollIt()` function call.

e.g. :

```
$.scrollIt({
   activeClass:'active'
});
```

and make sure the class name you mention has some CSS attached to it.

e.g. :

```
a.active {
  background: #000;
  color: fff;
}
```